# Por qué al usar mi Matcher me da NPE

Tags: java, maven, junit-5, hamcrest

Me gustaría verificar la renderización correcta de componentes personalizados Swing, para ello viendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986875/6999690) se me ocurrió hacer un matcher

## Código

#### Gradient Panel

```
package com.toedter.components;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;

/**
 *
 * @author Ruslan Lopez Carro
 * @author Kai Toedter
 */
public class GradientPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6385751027379193053L;

    private Color background;

    private Color controlColor;

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
    /**
     * Creates new form GradientPanel
     */
    public GradientPanel() {
        this(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public GradientPanel(Color background) {
        // Color controlColor = UIManager.getColor("control");
        // Color controlColor = new Color(252, 198, 82);
//        Color controlColor = new Color(165, 201, 215);
        this(background, new Color(99, 153, 255));
    }

    public GradientPanel(Color background, Color controlColor) {
        this.background = background;
        this.controlColor = controlColor;
        initComponents();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (isOpaque()) {
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Paint oldPaint = g2.getPaint();
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, getBackground(), width, 0,
                    controlColor));
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        setBackground(background);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

}
```

#### Gradient panel page object

```
package com.toedter.pageobject.components;

import com.toedter.components.GradientPanel;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.ContainerOperator;
import org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JFrameOperator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GradientPanelPageObject {
    private ContainerOperator<GradientPanel> componentPanel;


    public GradientPanelPageObject(String title) {
        ContainerOperator<JFrame> containerFrame = new JFrameOperator(title);
        componentPanel = new ContainerOperator<>(containerFrame,3);
    }

    public Image getComponentImage() {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(componentPanel.getWidth(),componentPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        componentPanel.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();
        return componentPanel.createImage(componentPanel.getWidth(),componentPanel.getHeight());
    }
}
```

#### Gradient panel test

```
package com.toedter.components;

import com.toedter.matchers.DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher;
import com.toedter.pageobject.components.GradientPanelPageObject;
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;


public class GradientPanelTest {
    private GradientPanel gradientPanel;
    private JFrame frame;
    private GradientPanelPageObject pageObject;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("creating JFrame");
        frame = new JFrame("AJFrame");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown(){
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
        frame = null;
    }

    public void secondSetup(){
        frame.add(gradientPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        pageObject = new GradientPanelPageObject("AJFrame");
        System.out.println("JFrame should be visible");
    }

    @Test
    void withoutColorSpecified() {
        gradientPanel = new GradientPanel();
        secondSetup();
        Color defaultBackgroundColor = new Color(99, 153, 255);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(gradientPanel.getWidth(), gradientPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        gradientPanel.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(bi, DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher.looksLike((BufferedImage) pageObject.getComponentImage(),new Dimension(gradientPanel.getSize())));
    }

    @Test
    void someColorSpecified() {
        Random r = new Random();
        Color myColor = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
        gradientPanel = new GradientPanel(myColor);
        secondSetup();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Dmensions:"+gradientPanel.getSize());
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(386, 363, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        gradientPanel.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();
        Matcher<Object> matcher = DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher.looksLike((BufferedImage) pageObject.getComponentImage(),
                new Dimension(gradientPanel.getSize()));
        System.out.println("Matcher:"+matcher);
        MatcherAssert.assertThat("hazelnuts", 3, CoreMatchers.equalTo(3));
        MatcherAssert.<BufferedImage>assertThat(
                bi,
                matcher
        );
    }

    @Test
    void bothColorsSpecified() {
        Random r = new Random();
        Color myColor = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
        Color myColor1 = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
        gradientPanel = new GradientPanel(myColor, myColor1);
        secondSetup();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//        assertEquals(myColor, pageObject.getBackgroundColor());
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(gradientPanel.getWidth(), gradientPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        gradientPanel.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(bi, DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher.looksLike((BufferedImage) pageObject.getComponentImage(),new Dimension(gradientPanel.getSize())));
    }

    @Test
    void bothColorsSpecifiedButNoOpacity() {
        Random r = new Random();
        Color myColor = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
        Color myColor1 = new Color(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
        gradientPanel = new GradientPanel(myColor, myColor1);
        gradientPanel.setOpaque(false);
        gradientPanel.setVisible(true);
        secondSetup();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(gradientPanel.getWidth(), gradientPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        gradientPanel.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();
        gradientPanel.setVisible(false);

        MatcherAssert.assertThat(bi,
                DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher.looksLike((BufferedImage) pageObject.getComponentImage(),
                new Dimension(gradientPanel.getSize())));
    }
}
```

#### DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher

```
package com.toedter.matchers;

import com.toedter.util.ImageDifferentiator;
import net.avh4.util.imagecomparison.ImageComparison;
import net.avh4.util.imagecomparison.ImageComparisonResult;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.DiagnosingMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher extends DiagnosingMatcher<Object> {

    private final BufferedImage referenceImage;
    private final Dimension referenceImageSize;

    private DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher(BufferedImage referenceImage, Dimension referenceImageSize) {
        this.referenceImage = referenceImage;
        this.referenceImageSize = referenceImageSize;
    }

    protected boolean matches(Object item, Description mismatchDescription) {
        ImageComparisonResult result = ImageComparison.compare(item, this.referenceImage);
        if (result.isEqual()) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.referenceImage == null) {
            mismatchDescription.appendText("approval image ");
            mismatchDescription.appendText(" doesn't exist -- expected to find it in ");
            return false;
        } else {
            mismatchDescription.appendText("images don't match: ");
            mismatchDescription.appendText(result.getFailureMessage());
            try {
                File imagesDir = new File(System.getProperty("differingImagesFolder"));
                if (!imagesDir.exists()) {
                    imagesDir.mkdir();
                }
                Random r = new Random();
                String fileName = imagesDir + "/comparisionFailed"+r.nextInt(12383)+".png";
                System.out.println("diff image should be created at " + fileName);
                ImageDifferentiator.createDiffImage(referenceImage, (BufferedImage) item, fileName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        if (this.referenceImage == null) {
            description.appendText("reference image to exist");
        } else {
            description.appendText(String.format("something that looks like (%dx%d)", this.referenceImageSize.width, this.referenceImageSize.height));
        }

    }

    public static Matcher<Object> looksLike(BufferedImage referenceImage, Dimension referenceImageSize) {
        return new DirectImageLooksLikeMatcher(referenceImage, referenceImageSize);
    }
}
```

#### ImageDifferentiator

```
package com.toedter.util;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageDifferentiator {

    private static void createPngImage(BufferedImage image, String fileName) throws IOException {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));
    }

    private static void createJpgImage(BufferedImage image, String fileName) throws IOException {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(fileName));
    }

    public static void createDiffImage(BufferedImage referenceImage, BufferedImage anotherImage, String fileName) throws IOException {
        int height = referenceImage.getHeight();
        int width = referenceImage.getWidth();
        BufferedImage rImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                try {
                    int pixelC = anotherImage.getRGB(x, y);
                    int pixelB = referenceImage.getRGB(x, y);
                    if (pixelB == pixelC ) {
                        rImage.setRGB(x, y,  referenceImage.getRGB(x, y));
                    } else {
                        int a= 0xff |  referenceImage.getRGB(x, y)>>24 ,
                                r= 0xff &  referenceImage.getRGB(x, y)>>16 ,
                                g= 0,
                                b= 0;

                        int modifiedRGB=a<<24|r<<16|g<<8|b;
                        rImage.setRGB(x,y,modifiedRGB);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // handled hieght or width mismatch
                    rImage.setRGB(x, y, 0x80ff0000);
                }
            }
        }
        String fileExtenstion = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'), fileName.length());
        if (fileExtenstion.toUpperCase().contains("PNG")) {
            createPngImage(rImage, fileName);
        } else {
            createJpgImage(rImage, fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Mi POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>jcalendar-swing</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
        <version>1.3.9</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>jcalendar-testing-api</artifactId>

    <name>jcalendar-testing-api</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>imagecomparison</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- if you will be comparing AWT components, Swing JComponents or JFrames: -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>imagecomparison-swing</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        automated GUI testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>jemmy-2.3.1.1</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>RELEASE110</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javatlacati</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <propertyName>differingImagesFolder</propertyName>
                        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}/diffImages</buildDirectory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- code coverage -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pero al probar mediante maven me causa NPE.

> creating JFrame
>
> ```
> Trace:
> Start to wait frame "Frame with title "AJFrame"" opened
> Trace:
> Frame "Frame with title "AJFrame"" has been opened in 0 milliseconds
>     javax.swing.JFrame[frame20,0,0,400x400,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=AJFrame,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,7,30,386x363,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
> Trace:
> Start to wait action "Wait Any java.awt.Container loaded (ComponentOperator.WaitComponentTimeout)"
> Trace:
> "Wait Any java.awt.Container loaded (ComponentOperator.WaitComponentTimeout)" action has been produced in
> ```
>
> 0 milliseconds with result 
>           : com.toedter.components.GradientPanel[,0,0,386x363,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
>       JFrame should be visible
>       Dmensions:java.awt.Dimension[width=386,height=363]
>       Matcher:something that looks like (386x363)
>       [ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.325 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   com.toedter.components.GradientPanelTest
>       [ERROR] bothColorsSpecified  Time elapsed: 2.143 s  <<< ERROR!
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.toedter.components.GradientPanelTest.bothColorsSpecified(GradientPanelTest.java:103)
>
> ```
> [ERROR] bothColorsSpecifiedButNoOpacity  Time elapsed: 2.067 s  <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.toedter.components.GradientPanelTest.bothColorsSpecifiedButNoOpacity(GradientPanelTest.java:126)
>
> [ERROR] withoutColorSpecified  Time elapsed: 0.054 s  <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.toedter.components.GradientPanelTest.withoutColorSpecified(GradientPanelTest.java:57)
>
> [ERROR] someColorSpecified  Time elapsed: 2.053 s  <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.toedter.components.GradientPanelTest.someColorSpecified(GradientPanelTest.java:80)
> ```

Comment: Seria bueno que dejaras el enlace de github con una replica funcional. simplemente para impotarlo con maven

Comment: @JGarnica aun no subo los cmabios, pero el repo puedes hallarlo en https://github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar

Comment: Cambios tal cual en la pregunta en esta rama: https://github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar/tree/experiments